# using IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR makes my thumb too much blury

Tags: php

so im using my class to resize an image to a very little thumb, and im trying to blur that thumb in order to have a decent image and not some broken image all pixaleted. but IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR its a little TOO MUCH.

```
imagefilter($newImg, IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR);
                imagefilter($newImg, IMG_FILTER_EDGEDETECT);
                imagejpeg($newImg, $this->getImage(), 90);
```

is there any decent way to have a good quality thumbnail from a picture?

Comment: if the image is resized from a larger image it should not be pixelated

Comment: actually it is going to be... but i found the solution unsing     imagecopyresampled($newImg, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $this->newWidth, $this->newHeight, $this->width, $this->height);
              imagejpeg($newImg, $this->getImage(), 90);

Answer (score 0):

i find the solution by using this function:

```
imagecopyresampled($newImg, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $this->newWidth, $this->newHeight, $this->width, $this->height);
                imagejpeg($newImg, $this->getImage(), 90);
```

it really makes a perfect sample with the best quality possible for it size!!

:)